# How to un-bin the binned data

Tags: r, binning

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    bin        val
    A-B-C     0.345
    K-P       0.612
```

I would like to un-bin the data above into the following using R

```
    bin val
    A   0.345
    B   0.345
    C   0.345
    K   0.621
    P   0.621
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(bin, sep = "-")

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  bin     val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     0.345
2 B     0.345
3 C     0.345
4 K     0.612
5 P     0.612
```